# How to show pickerView in ipad actionSheet using tabBarItems

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I was trying to add pickerView in actionSheet in ios and was successfull in displaying in iPhone pictures shown below:
[this is on iphone8 and actionSheet is working as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7RRy.png)

[this is on iPad and pickerView is not displaying anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjzWQ.png)

the code which I implemented is as below:

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{
    let CheckInList = ["Site 1","Site 2","Site 3","Site 4"]
    @IBOutlet weak var homeTabBar: UITabBar!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        homeTabBar.delegate = self;
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return CheckInList.count
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return CheckInList[row]
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(CheckInList[row], forKey: "CheckInSelected")
    }
}
```

this is how I implemented tabBarItem code

```
func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    print(item.title!)
    switch item.title! {
    case "Check in":
        self.checkInAction()
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

and this is my checkInAction function:

```
func checkInAction(){
    let alertView: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "CheckIn", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let height:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertView.view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: self.view.frame.height * 0.35)
    alertView.view.addConstraint(height);

    let pickerView: UIPickerView = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: alertView.view.frame.width - 18, height: height.constant - 60));
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self

    if let row = CheckInList.firstIndex(of: selected) {
        pickerView.selectRow(row, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
    }
    alertView.view.addSubview(pickerView)

    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alertView.addAction(action)

    if let popoverController = alertView.popoverPresentationController {
        popoverController.sourceView = self.view
        popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
        popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = []
    }

    self.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I would like some help for resolving this issue on ipad. I do know with my study that on ios ipad we can't show action sheet and my study is from the core documentation and some of helper links.

Comment: It seems like you might need to create the `pickerView` variable as a global one to the class.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr you mean outside the function? i'll try it out and let you know

Comment: @syedmuttaqeenrizvi no issue with ipad or coding you need to just change width of uipicker view check my answer

Comment: @Akhilrajtr I think there is no need take pickerView as global

Comment: @JaydeepVyas that is correct!

Comment: @JaydeepVyas your answer is helpful but cant upvote due to less reputation but i'll do that once i am able to cheers

Comment: @syedmuttaqeenrizvi thank you

Comment: Don't do this. From the documentation for `UIAlertController`: *"The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified."*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge there is no issue in code or ipad 
Just you have given Wrong Width to UIPickerView

Just Replace your code with this

```
 let pickerView: UIPickerView = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: 270, height: height.constant - 60));
```

**width: 270** change as per your requirement
but (270 width x 144 height) which is default size of uialert

[image]

as you set UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: alertView.view.frame.width - 18, height: height.constant - 60));

which means it start from 0 and take whole view width (-18) which is correct in terms of actionSheet but not from alert.

Answer (score 0):

this resolved my issue , just wanted to share the solution with mates for future.

```
 if let popoverController = alertView.popoverPresentationController {
        popoverController.sourceView = self.view
        popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
        popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = []

        height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertView.view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: self.view.frame.height * 0.25)
         pickerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: 300, height: height.constant - 60);
    }
```

i changed the pickerview frame width to 300 and re-calculated the height in this popOverController which fixed my issue.